# Regular expression annotation is not working ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Regular expressions for two types of fields to allow only long and double values.

The strange thing is it worked in the beginning and now it stopped working. My code is the following:

```
        [Display(Name = "Număr elemente per unitate")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "The field only allows numbers!")]
        public long NumarUnitatiBax
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

and

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field can't be empty!")]
        [Display(Name = "Cantitate ambalaj total")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*([.,][0-9]{1,3})?$", ErrorMessage = "The field only allows numbers with 3 decimal numbers!")]
        [VerificaAmbalajTotal]
        public double CantitateAmbalajTotal
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

and in the cshtml:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Produs.NumarUnitatiBax)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Produs.NumarUnitatiBax, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Produs.NumarUnitatiBax)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Produs.CantitateAmbalajTotal)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Produs.CantitateAmbalajTotal, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Produs.CantitateAmbalajTotal)
    </div>
```

and the C# (even if I think it does not matter):

```
                var produsViewModel = new ProdusViewModel
                {
                    Produs = produs,
                    DateFirma = baseViewModel.DateFirma,
                    Furnizor = _context.Furnizor.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Cod == produs.CodFurnizor),
                    TipUnitateAmbalare = _context.TipUnitateAmbalare.ToList()
                };

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    return View("AdaugaProdus", produsViewModel);
```

But it is not checking it or the message I overwritten in the "ErrorMessage" does not appear:

[image]

I can make my own Annotation and it works, but I am wondering what I am doing wrong now.

As I have said, it worked a few days ago. I tried and tried to find what I have changed for it not to work anymore, but I am unable to identify what changes I have made for it to stop working.

Edit: As I have said in a comment in Ajit Kumar's answer, I changed the browser to one I haven't used for this project and it is still not working. So, it is not a cache problem.

Comment: Why do you code in Romanian? :)

Comment: Because the IT in Romania (for the Romanian market) is growing and I am developing an application for multiple companies :)

Comment: Ok, but I'm surprised to see that the classes and properties names are not English. I can only remember when we had to continue work on a huge project that was all in Dutch. It was really difficult to understand it.